# Having problems coding a char array to a string

Tags: java

I'm trying to use a string constructor to convert the 2d char array into a string.  Having problems finding the proper constructor. I attempted using various constructors but nothing seems to work.

Comment: How would a 2D character array map into one string?

Comment: It sounds like you're operating at far lower levels of abstraction than you need to / should be.  Why have an array of array of chars?  This is Java, not C.  If you're reading all the lines of a file, I would suspect you can get an array or List of Strings.  In which case you can create a StringBuilder, loop over all the strings, add them to the string builder, and put a "\n" in between each string.  Use the resulting string in the setText method.

Comment: @Cameron I was told I had to convert a 2d char array to display the array in a GUI.  The setText only takes in a string.

Comment: @I82Much I am building a word mole game for class assignment.  You take in a word from JOptionPane, and then compare it to the 10x10 array of characters.  If the word matches the letters in the array we erase the letters from the array

Comment: Why is it not possible to iterate through the 2D-array and buffer each iterated item into a string in the format you want?

Comment: Folks ... this is HOMEWORK ... he has got enough hints now!

Comment: @Bunker:You don't have a constructor for 2d array in string but for 1d array it has.Check my [ans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939275/having-problems-coding-a-char-array-to-a-string/3939781#3939781).

Answer (score 1):

```
char chars[][]= {{'a', 'b', 'c'}, {'d', 'e', 'f'}};

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

     for(int i = 0; i<2 ;i++){

         for(int j =0; j<3; j++){


             sb.append(chars[i][j]);

         }

     }


        System.out.print(sb.toString());
```

**this is one of my option to do .. nevertheless.. there might be a good code!! look for it!!!**

Comment: I tried your method but its saying that setText can't be used with string builder.

Comment: @Mister Bunker - Hint - look at the javadocs for StringBuilder.

Comment: @Mister Bunker There is no method call setText in StringBuilder and and i did not use it !!

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a list of String's

```
    char[][] arr={{'a', 'b', 'c'}, {'d', 'e', 'f'}};
    List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
    for(char[] ar:arr)
    {
        list.add(new String(ar));
    }
```

If you want the 2d char array as a single string:

```
    StringBuilder b=new StringBuilder();//use string builder instead of list
    for(char[] ar:arr)
    {
        b.append(new String(ar));
    }
```

If you simply want to print the char 2d array:

```
Arrays.deepToString(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean a 2d char array into a string?

If you have this: {{'a', 'b', 'c'}, {'d', 'e', 'f'}}

Do you want the result to be: "abcdef"?

Comment: I'm reading in an input file of characters.  I'm placing the characters in a char array.  Now I want to display the array into a GUI.  But the setText method only takes in strings.

Answer (score 0):

You want to turn a 2d char array into a single string? Seems kind of strange. Do you want to just concatenate each row at the end of the last row?

Long story short, I don't think you will find a built in constructor to do that. You are probably going to have to write something to do that conversion on your own.

**EDIT:**
Based on your comments it looks like you are using the wrong data structure when you originally read the file. Here is a code snippet to read an entire file into a string so you don't have to do any conversion later.

```
  StreamReader MyStreamReader = new StreamReader(@"c:\Projects\Testing.txt");
  string fileContents= MyStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
  MyStreamReader.Close();
```

Comment: How would I start something like that.  I'm a beginner Java programmer.

Comment: Based on your comment on Ryan's answer. I think you need to take one step back to the core problem. You should read the data in one line at a time into a string or 1d character array and the problem is moot. If you post your code that reads the file, I can help you in more detail.

Comment: The assignment calls for reading the input file and placing the data into a 10x10 array of characters.

Comment: Ahhhh. Homework, a mythical land of hypothetical and impractical problems. =) In that case you probably just need to write a nested loop to concatenate each element of the 2d array into a string.